# Why does an enum declared in the global scope explicitly require no terminating semicolon?

Tags: rust

If we explicitly add `;` at the end of an enum declaration in the global scope, the compiler will complain.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Organs{
    Head,
    Tail,
};

fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", Organs::Head);
}
```

The resulting error message is

```
enums.rs:5:2: 5:3 error: expected item, found `;`
enums.rs:5 };
```

However, when declared within a function, the statement terminators are not mandatory, the program will compile with or without `;`.

```
fn main(){
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Organs{
        Head,
        Tail,
    };
    println!("{:?}", Organs::Head);
}
```

I wasted good chunk of time (just now) determining what the compiler was complaining about. It didn't occur to me that enum declaration (in the global scope) can't be terminated with `;`. Why is this inconsistency present (or am I misunderstanding anything) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inconsistency.  What you've written in the function is an `enum` item, *an empty statement*, and a statement containing an expression macro invocation.

Comment: Indeed `fn main() { ;;;;; }` does actually compile !

Comment: my actual problem is not with the second example but with the first example. Why is that, terminating the enum declaration in the global scope with `;` produces compiler error ?

Comment: @basic_bgnr: You *are not* terminating the enum declaration with a `;`---you are writing an empty statement, and you can't have statements at module level.  Note that there are some declaration forms that *require* a semicolon (such as writing a `struct` or `enum` with no members), but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @DK. but can't we use `use, static` etc. statement at module level. why can't we have empty statement at top level ? what is the logic behind preventing the use of empty  `;` at module level ?

Comment: Because those *are not statements*.  They're *items*, and there is no "empty item" item.  The logic is simply that the grammar is constructed such that you cannot have a lone `;` at module level.